# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the 'chromedriver' error when using Python3 on Windows OS

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm using a Windows 7 OS and trying to run a selenium webdriver test using python from my Eclipse+ PyDev IDE. I have downloaded the Google Chrome driver and added it to my path. I've also added the `chromedriver.exe` to `C:\Python34\Scripts`. I have tried the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I get the error message

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the 'chromedriver'

when I try to run my script. I've also tried the following:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\folder\chromedriver.exe")
```

I get a message saying file cannot be found. If I try the following from the terminal:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

The browser is launched so it works from the terminal. The issue is running my script from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I work with this on Ubuntu but i came across the same kind of error, the problem was that i didn't have a sym-link to the chrome driver file,

In Ubuntu it is 
`sudo ln -s ~/selgrid/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

This might help
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Good Luck!

Comment: I've since found that there was a setting which I added to my path(DEBUG=true) which now allows the browser to be launched so I'm now able to run the tests from eclipse. Thanks once again.